# Why does Xcode 5 refuse to recognize my icons when dragging from Finder into the Asset Catalog?

Tags: icons, ios7, xcode5

Both click&drag from Finder and Import... with Xcode 5 are failing (doing nothing) when I attempt to bring Icon29.PNG, Icon29@2x.PNG, Icon40.PNG, Icon40@2x.PNG, Icon60.PNG, Icon60@2x.PNG, Icon76.PNG and Icon76@2x.PNG into my new iOS 7 project.

Answer (score 0):

With upper-case extensions (.PNG), the files will not be recognized.  Rename the extensions as lower-case (.png) and the process will work perfectly.